# Database schema for a defect tracking system

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-schema

I want to build the following defect detection system in SQL Server. The interface will be built using ASP.NET . but currently i am struggled on how to build the Database tables the relation between these tables.

the system allow to create a report >> select the report type,Equipment ID & other info >> select the wanted categories (by choosing Y or N) >> and for the selected category >> select the defect details and enter the comments..

[image]

I came out with this schema (Table names & Columns):-

Equipment

- ID
- Name

Operator

- ID
- Name

Report Type

- ID
- Name

Report

- ID
- Operator ID (FK to Operator),
- Name
- Equipment ID (FK to Equipment)
- Type ID (FK to Report Type)
- Date/Time
- Comments

ReportCategory

- ID
- Name

Part

- ID
- Name

ReportCategory

- Report ID (FK to Reports) -->PK
- Category ID (FK to Category) --> PK
- Yes/no

DefectDetailesLookup

- Part ID (FK to Part) ---> PK
- Cateogry ID (FK to Cateogry) ---> PK

ReportDefectDetails

- ReportID (FK to Report) --> PK
- Category ID (FK to Category) --> PK
- Part ID (FK to Part)-->PK
- Comment
- Yes/No

so are the schema valid? or i am missing something? thanks

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  The only thing that leaps out is the use of ID everywhere.  If there's an external ID you can use, like the Operator ID (I assume), great.  But generating IDs just for their own sake is a potential liability. For example, do you really want two parts with different IDs called *pins* or *bolts* ?

Comment: Schema is highly dependent on identified entities and relationships. Based on your description I don't see any issue. At this pint it might be best to do a first iteration on your app and release it for testing so that you can get feedback

Answer (score 0):

It would work.

There are a few things worth giving a thought for future changeability: Without fully understanding your applications domain: Give composite PKs a second thought. It is not necessarily a bad practise to use them, but if you use them make sure they are an integral part to the Entities Identity. And if you are not sure, I'd recommend to remove them and rather use an own Identity column for your Entity. Otherwise you are bound to having i.e. a Category for every ReportDefectDetail.

If you are not dependent on an existing database and assuming you already have your repository classes set up, give ef core and [code-first](https://entityframeworkcore.com/approach-code-first) a try. Also [DDD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/ddd-oriented-microservice) (domain driven design) is a worthy read. Modern db models are mostly code driven/domain driven. The time of dbs dictating how the code should be written are gone.

Aside from that:

1. little typo here: DefectDetail_e_sLookup
2. ReportCategory => exists two times. I guess the upper one is just Category
3. give your yes/no columns meaningful names, like isDisplayed

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Defect DEF named DEF_NME, with comment DEF_CMT exists.
--
defect {DEF, DEF_NME, DEF_CMT}
    PK {DEF}
    AK {DEF_NME}
```

```
-- Defect category CAT named CAT_NME exists.
--
dcat {CAT, CAT_NME}
  PK {CAT}
  AK {CAT_NME}
```

```
-- Defect DEF is in defect category CAT.
--
defect_category {DEF, CAT}
             PK {DEF, CAT}

FK1 {DEF} REFERENCES defect {DEF}
FK2 {CAT} REFERENCES dcat   {CAT}
```

```
--  Part PRT named PRT_NME exists.
--
part {PRT, PRT_NME}
  PK {PRT}
  AK {PRT_NME}
```

```
-- It is possible for part PRT to have defect DEF.
--
part_defect {PRT, DEF}
         PK {PRT, DEF}

FK1 {PRT} REFERENCES part   {PRT}
FK2 {DEF} REFERENCES defect {DEF}
```

```
-- Equipment EQP named EQP_NME exists.
--
equipment {EQP, EQP_NME}
       PK {EQP}
       AK {EQP_NME}
```

```
-- Equipment EQP contains part PRT.
--
equipment_part {EQP, PRT}
            PK {EQP, PRT}


FK1 {EQP} REFERENCES equipment {EQP}
FK2 {PRT} REFERENCES part      {PRT}
```

```
-- Operator 0PR named OPR_NME exists.
--
operator {0PR, OPR_NME}
      PK {0PR}
      AK {OPR_NME}
```

```
-- Report type RTY named RTP_NME exists.
--
report_type {RTY, RTP_NME}
         PK {RTY}
         AK {RTP_NME}
```

```
-- Report category RCT named RCT_NME exists.
--
report_cat {RCT, RCT_NME}
        PK {RCT}
       AK {RCT_NME}
```

```
-- Report REP, of report-type RTY, named REP_NME,
-- categorized in report-category RCT,
-- was submitted by operator OPR on date-time DTE,
-- for equipment EQP with comments REP_CMT.

report{REP, RTY, REP_NME, RCT, OPR, DTE, EQP, REP_CMT}
   PK {REP}
   AK {REP_NME}
   SK {REP, EQP}

FK1 {RTY} REFERENCES report_type {RTY}
FK2 {OPR} REFERENCES operator    {0PR}
FK3 {EQP} REFERENCES equipment   {EQP}
FK4 {RCT} REFERENCES report_cat  {RCT}
```

```
-- Defect DEF for part PRT of equipment EQP is reported in
-- report-detail number DET_NO of report REP; with 
-- additional comments DET_CMT. 
--
report_detail {REP, DET_NO, EQP, PRT, DEF, DET_CMT}
           PK {REP, DET_NO}

FK1 {REP, EQP} REFERENCES report         {REP, EQP}
FK2 {EQP, PRT} REFERENCES equipment_part {EQP, PRT}
FK3 {PRT, DEF} REFERENCES part_defect    {PRT, DEF}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```